# Timer is running over

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

It seems like I need some help (again :/). My actual problem is a Timer. I created a Timer to execute a specific function every n-seconds. So far everything works, but the function seems to run over time. Why I expect that? Well, I did some Console.Writes to see whats going on, and I saw that sometimes it looks like my Timer is doing everything two times at the same time ...

Maybe one example of my Output-Console:

```
Start_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:18 ]
 Stop_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:18 ]
Start_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:23 ]
__StopMonitoring
Start_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:32 ]
 Stop_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:32 ]
Start_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:32 ]
 Stop_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:32 ]
Start_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:37 ]
 Stop_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:37 ]
Start_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:37 ]
 Stop_Monitoring  [ 06.09.2013 11:16:37 ]
```

Start-/Stop Monitoring is the Console.Write on top and bot of my function which is getting executed by my timer. The __StopMonitoring means the function to stop the timer got executed. Following the Code-Parts:

```
    public void Start_Monitoring()
    {
        Console.Write("Start_Monitoring  [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[ " + System.DateTime.Now + " ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]\n");
        
        /* something will be done here ... */

        if (iCount_Popups > 0)
        {
            Stop_Monitoring();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            /* something will be done here ... */
        }
        Console.Write("Stop_Monitoring  [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[ " + System.DateTime.Now + " ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]\n\n\n\n\n");
    }

    public void Stop_Monitoring()
    {
        Console.Write("__StopMonitoring\n");
        myTimer.Stop();
    }

    // === #TIMER# ==================================================

    public System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    
    public void CreateTimer()
    {
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Event);
        myTimer.Interval = GeneralSettings.AdlibInterval;
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    public void Timer_Event(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        Start_Monitoring();
    }
    // =========================================================================
```

I don't know if this Code-Parts will be enough to get some help, if not, I'd really appreciate it if you would let me know this.

I also tried to work with the Timer.Interval. GeneralSettings.AdlibInterval is equal 5000 (ms). I already thought about the problem that the things should be done in the interval needs more time then the Interval. That's not the problem here. The highest time needed which I could see was 1 sec, so lets say 2 secs. But e.g. an Interval of at least 10000 ms would be a way to much for the usage of this application.

Maybe some other information:
Environment is Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express - Windows Desktop
Its an Windows-Form-Application
...and my first own C# Project. Therefore I assure that I did some research, but mostly I couldn't get solutions because everyone posted there code and nearly every time the mistake was done by the developer.

## Edit:

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        CreateTimer();
    }
```

Comment: You definitely calling CreateTimer() only once?

Comment: why do you have 
private void TimerEvent(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
twice?

Comment: I edited my first post. Totally forgot about the Start-Call. No I do not. If this is getting stopped I do the same call again. I already thought about that, that this maybe could be the problem, but i couldn't find him. --- I copied it just two times here sorry. i'll edit this.

Comment: can you provide the code where you start the timer again? i cant see how you check if the timer stopped.

Comment: I don't check it anymore, I just did some Console.Writes to see if he is still running or not. Okay, I admit its for sure not the best way to do it. But it still shows me that my function isn't running anymore. Besides, take a look on the post by "Alessandro D'Andria" ;) But thank you too.

Comment: if(myTimer.isrunning~)
myTimer.Stop(); 
should be used before starting

also you should add the eventhandler only once, by putting the timerconstruction in the Constructor.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)" and "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

Your CreateTimer method is adding another Tick handler every time you clicks a button, so your tick event will be called the number of times you clicked button1.

Set interval and Tick handler in form designer or in form initialization / show method.

Comment: I thought about this, and tried it, but I was so weird, I tried to set this just in the class definition without getting the idea of just pulling out the start-call. Thanks to you too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you click button1, you're creating a new timer. I think you should create timer in form constructor and start in button click event

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    myTimer.Start();
}
```

Sorry I didn't put attention on the new but on the event handler

```
myTimer += ...
```

Comment: Sometimes it can be so easy ... "-.- Doing this little change and my Timer-Problem is gone. Well I have a little problem with my listed listview-items. I thought this will be caused by this problem, but seems like it doesn't. I'll first give it a better look now again, but in case that I do not find it. May I ask here again? im pretty new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Isn't he creating a new timer here: 
public System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

He just starts it and sets the intervall, at leats it looks that way. But i think a Timer can have multiple instances started.

Comment: Well, you think the way I'm doing this is bad? Could u maybe give me some advice if you got the opinion that I should change this in a correct way even if this works?

Comment: You're registering many times the event, every time it fires call as many times your method.